# requested json parse failed ,there was an error parsing the json document

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

```
var objectData ={
             "emailAdress" :  document.getElementById('emailAddress').value ,
              "password":     document.getElementById('password').value }

 var objectDataString = JSON.stringify(objectData);
 alert(objectDataString);


   var url = "url";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    alert('connected..');
    }
  };
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(objectDataString);

      $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            URL:"login.php",
            contentType:"application/json",
            CrossDomain:true,
            data:  JSON.stringify(objectData),       
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                alert("success");
                var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                alert(ret);
```

I have login form which contains userid and password.i have to convert that user entered info into json and send it to the server.but getting json parsed error .unable to find the error.please tell me where i m doing wrong..?i m  trying from so many hours but unable to find .

Comment: It's impossible to say what's wrong, you **haven't shown what you're trying to parse**. Show what `data` contains as of when you try to parse it.

Comment: Why are you using XHR directly, *and* using jQuery's `ajax`? This will send the request twice.

Comment: And note that `ajax` has no `CrossDomain` option. JavaScript is case sensitive. There's a `crossDomain` option.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the XHR code, and just looking at the `ajax` call:

1. There's no `CrossDomain` option. There's a `crossDomain` option, though. (JavaScript is case-sensitive.) You probably don't want that option at all, though, with the URL you're giving.
2. You're telling jQuery that the data coming back is JSON. That means jQuery will parse it for you before giving you the `data` argument to your success function. You don't need (or want) to call `JSON.parse` on it, that's already been done for you. `data` will be parsed data.